# Alert+form+j2me

Tags: java, java-me

Hello
I m working on j2me application.
There is one form in which I had used the `choicegroup(check box)`.Now I want that whenever user select the options of the choicegroup(check box) one POP-up or dialogbox or Alert which ask user that if you select this item.Then this item get deleted form the list.
The POP-up or dialogbox or Alert contain:-

> Text :--Do you want to delete this
>   item?
>
> Two command or two options or
>   button :--1)YES 2)NO

If I keep alert then can I able to keep two command in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an alert

```
alert = new Alert("alert");
alert.addCommand(new Command("Ok", Command.OK, 0));
alert.addCommand(new Command("Cancel", Command.CANCEL, 0););
alert.setCommandListener(this);
alert.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
```

And in `CommandAction`

```
 if (displayable == alert) {
        if (command == cancelCommand) {
                //user denied
        } else if (command == okCommand1) {
              //user accepts
        }
    }
```